# Add to blocklist after too many request nginx

Tags: nginx, request, spam

I'm looking for a way to automatically block an IP permanently if this IP does more than X request per second in Nginx

I saw that the `limit_req` and `limit_req_zone` directive exists, but from what i saw, they just forbid an IP to do more than X request per second but doesn't block the IP to avoid this IP to do more request.

Is there a way to do create a blocklist of IP that exceeded the `limit_req` and deny them permanently ?